# Hibernate - Envers - Multiple Audit targets

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-envers

I am already using Hibernate Envers to audit entities that are updated by a user through the UI; however, I also have asynchronous jobs running in the background and would like to audit those as well using Envers.  Now, for the UI, I track which HttpRequest made the change which gives me the date, user, session, etc.  For the background jobs, I would like to track the date the job was run as well as the exact job that modified it (job class).

Is it possible to setup 2 Audit entities, 1 for the UI, and 1 for the system changes?

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this out yet, but I am simply doing the following:

```
@RevisionListener(SystemRevisionListener.class)
@Entity
public class SystemRevision extends AbstractRevision
{
   @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
   protected QuartzTriggerHandle job;

   @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
   protected Class jobClass;

   ...
}



@RevisionListener(WebRevisionListener.class)
@Entity
public class WebRevision extends AbstractRevision
{
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
   protected HttpRequest httpRequest;

   ...
}
```

Then, in each listener, I do whatever I need to do to set these properties.  I should now be able to track how an entity as modified, if a user did the change (and what request it is tied into), or if the system changed the entity, what job is responsible for the change.  I would be storing more properties in the SystemRevision than this, most likely the arguments and method name.